# Creating Accordion using JSON Data

Tags: javascript, jquery

While developing the functionality of the accordion by populating the data from JSON. I'm facing an issue that all the accordion is opening together. Can anyone please help me?

**By default it is looking like this:**
[image]

**But after clicking on a single one all the tabs are expanding. Now it's looking like this:**
[image]

[Link of jsFiddle for reference](https://jsfiddle.net/abhishek_kumar_13092/abLf93t8/220/)

```
var JSONData = [{
  "name": "Jenkins",
  "location": "Pune",
  "role": "Testing",
  "branches": [{
    "name": "Jenkins_pune1",
    "location": "Pune_Hin",
    "role": "Testing_Automation",
    "id": "PUN_HINJE_T122"
  }, {
    "name": "Jenkins_pune2",
    "location": "Pune_DC",
    "role": "Testing_UI",
    "id": "PUN_DC_TDC121"
  }, {
    "name": "Jenkins_pune3",
    "location": "Pune_SEZ",
    "role": "Testing_Black",
    "id": "PUN_DC_TDC121"
  }]
}, {
  "name": "UI/UX",
  "location": "Delhi",
  "role": "UI_Dev",
  "branches": [{
    "name": "UIUX_Del1",
    "location": "Del_Sec1",
    "role": "UI",
    "id": "Del_Sec1_T122"
  }, {
    "name": "UIUX_Del2",
    "location": "Del_Sec3",
    "role": "Testing_UI",
    "id": "Del_Sec3_TDC121"
  }]
}, {
  "name": "Back-End",
  "location": "Mumbai",
  "role": "Dev",
  "branches": [{
    "name": "Dev_Mum1",
    "location": "Mum_Sec1",
    "role": "Dev",
    "id": "Mum_Sec1_Dv122"
  }, {
    "name": "Dev_Mum2",
    "location": "Mum_Sec3",
    "role": "Dev",
    "id": "Mum_Sec3_Dev21"
  }]
}]
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.id = "mainContainer";
div.className = "mainContainer";



JSONData.forEach(function(data, index) {
  div.innerHTML += '<div id=' + data.name + ' class="unitName">' + '<p class="roleName">' + data.name + '</p>' + '</div>';
  document.getElementById("container").appendChild(div);

  var innerDiv = document.createElement('div');
  innerDiv.id = "innerContainer";
  innerDiv.className = "innerContainer"

  data.branches.forEach((branch) => {
    innerDiv.innerHTML += '<div class="branchDetails"><p id=' + branch.name + ' class="branchName">' + branch.name + '</p></div>'

    document.getElementById(data.name).appendChild(innerDiv);
  })

})


var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("roleName");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = document.getElementsByClassName("branchDetails")
    var j;
    if (this.classList.contains('active')) {
      for (j = 0; j < panel.length; j++) {
        if (panel[j].style.maxHeight) {
          panel[j].style.maxHeight = null;
        } else {
          panel[j].style.maxHeight = panel[j].scrollHeight + "px";
        }
      }
    }

  });
}
```

> This is the JS code that I created.

Comment: You *probably* don't want to use `div id=${data.name}` because your data.name contains non-alpha characters.  While this is allowed, actually *using* those can be a pain, eg `$("#UI/UX")` -> `unrecognized expression`.  Use `data-id=${data.name}` instead.

Comment: Your issue is likely `var panel = document.getElementsByClassName("branchDetails")` - which gets all of the `branchDetails` sub-panel**s**.  For jquery you would use `$(this).find(".branchDetails")` so maybe `var panel = this.getElementsByClassName("branchDetails")`